# MDL add checked checkbox in a table

Tags: javascript, html, material-design-lite

I'm working on a To Do app for myself and I want to have a check system. I'm using MDL (material design light) for this project, but find the documentation quite restricted. I would like to add a item to a list that already has the checkbox set to true/checked.

I found code from someone else that has got this function, but I don't really understand it. Could somebody please explain it to me (I'm also using a older JS version, so this syntax is completely new to me). This is the link https://codepen.io/pespantelis/pen/pjbvBL, I changed the completed on line 36 to true and got the exact function that I want.

My HTML (that I than add to the page with JS) which adds items without an checked checkbox looks like this

```
<tr>
 <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Thing to do</td>
 <td><i class="material-icons md-18 delete">clear</i><i class="id">ID</i></td>
</tr>
```

and it would be amazing if I could do the same with some slight tweaks to get the MDL version working with a ticked checkbox!

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand what your question is but the code pen you provided the checkbox is not working for new tasks added as the new tasks you're adding are not being assigned an id which is needed to identify the id, something like `var task = { id: Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), body: value, completed: false};` try looking into uuids

Comment: I've already build my own ID system which works perfectly, the only problem is inserting the check into the checkbox when I load a previously saved item that has checked = true (as object property). I just used to codepen to demonstrate how a checkbox which is checked can be added, but I don't really understand the code, I just found it on an other stackoverflow page. Could you please explain the body: completed: true/false for me? I don't really understand how it actually makes the checkbox ticked.

Comment: The checkbox is checked depending on the value set in the `v-model` for the input see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html thus by passing `v-model="task.completed"` into the checkbox is is checked if `task.completed` is truthy and not otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, I never knew about vue.js (my own script only uses plain js, while it does have acces to JQuery). I learned something valuable today. Now I understand the codepen a lot better!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, while I was trying some things out I made a typo, when trying some things over I found the solution. The working html that I should insert looks like this:

```
<tr class="is-selected">
 <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Thing to do</td>
 <td>
     <i class="material-icons md-18 delete">clear</i>
     <i class="id">ID</i>
 </td>
```

Thank you all for your help!